How to move the GitHub Folder
i have a simple question. I currently have all my repositories under this path (Windows 11):
C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Guthub\
what I want to do is simply to move the GitHub folder to:
C:\Github\
so that all my repos will be ube under this path:
C:\GitHub\repo1\ instead of C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Guthub\repo1\
my fear is that GitHub Desktop or even Source Tree that i'm using could stop working. I did something like this in the past with no success.
can someone tell me a safe procedure in order to avoid problems?
thank you very much!
Francesco
i expect that when i move the folder, GitHub goes in error because it doesn't find the previous path

First of all, Github doesn't have anything related to your local path. Github Desktop has.
You need to move .git(It is hidden) directory when you move your content from one directory to another. Then just open GitHub Desktop or Source Tree and point to new location. Similar: Change Git repository directory location.
